# Read items from External list in Sandbox Solution

Tags: sandbox-solution, external-list

Can we read an external content type using a sandbox solution for share point online? If anyone has faced this issue then please share how is it possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes off course you can,

If you can use Client Object Model then follow this article,

[Code Snippets: Using the SharePoint Client Object Model with External Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464372.aspx)

OR

> External lists enable you to view and manipulate external data in the
>   same way that you can view and manipulate data stored in regular
>   SharePoint lists. In this reference implementation, we deploy a
>   sandboxed solution that includes external lists. The solution
>   demonstrates how sandboxed Web Parts can query and present the data
>   provided by the external lists.

[Reference Implementation: External Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798440.aspx)

Saying all that you might run into permission problems while implementing the solution, so if you do then read article below to give you needed permissions,

[BCS : Access Denied. You do not have permission to access this content](http://lightningtools.com/sharepoint_2010/bcs-access-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-this-content/)

You didn't mentioned which version of SharePoint you are using but if it's online then you can follow this guide ;)

[PROGRAMMING WITH EXTERNAL LISTS IN SHAREPOINT ONLINE (OFFICE 365)](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2011/11/programming-with-external-lists-in.html)

Comment: Thanks Raja... The links that you have provded is really helpful but all have used client side object model for the purpose. Is there any way in which we can access the items of external content type using server side object model?

Comment: Yes I am using Sharepoint Online. Is there any way to access the list item from code behind?